# Angular - Redirect to a Route from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

How do I properly redirect a user to a route in Angular in from JavaScript?

Most of the redirection that I'm doing is simply from clicking a link, and this works great.

```
<a href="#main">Main</a>
```

However, if I do something like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="performLogin()">Login</button>

$scope.performExternalLogin = function () {
    DoSomeAuthenticationStuff();
    window.location.href = "/#main";
}
```

This works the first time, but when the user does it a second time, I get an exception from Angular.
I suspect that there's a better way to redirect to a route, but my Googling skills have not come through for me.
I'd appreciate any help.

Here's the exception:
  Unhandled exception at line 112, column 381 in  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular you should use the **[`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location)** service to interract with the window's location:

```
$scope.performExternalLogin = function () {
    DoSomeAuthenticationStuff();
    $location.path('/main');   // Will redirect to `#/main`
}
```